# How to Style LoggedInTemplate in ASP?

Tags: asp.net, css

Im having trouble moving the LoggedInTemplate in my website,ive tried several ways to style it in CSS by wrapping it in div,span or adding an ID, I also tried to use the given ID HeadLoginName and HeadLoginStatus, but it doesnt work this is the code:

```
         <LoggedInTemplate>
        Hello <asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" />!
        <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log-out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/>
        </LoggedInTemplate>
```

and this is the screenshot, i want to move the LoggedInTemplate at the top right of the screen
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FCDY.png][1]

Comment: The LoggedInTemplate renders as standard HTML code e.g. Hello <span id="ParentContainer_HeadLoginName">John smith</span>! so just think of it as normal markup and build your HTML/CSS the same as you would without the template.

Comment: sir i fixed my problem by adding CssClass attribute to the ASP mark-up , anyway thanks for your response sir @luke2012 :)

Comment: Post it as answer and select it as best answer to your question.

Comment: thank you, i didnt know that. im new here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed my problem by adding CssClass attribute to the ASP mark-up. thanks on responding guys :)